# Marking a tool as a favorite in QGIS

Tags: qgis, search, toolbox

Is it possible to mark a QGIS tool in the `Processing Toolbox` as a favorite to speed up the search for it?

[image]

I know that you can search for tools by name, but this doesn't suit me, because I often look for tools with a common word in the name (e.g., `Lines to polygons`).

The `Recently used` group is not suitable because it may only contain 5 tools.

Comment: There's an open feature request regarding this topic:
https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/29220

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you go in Settings -> Options -> Processing -> Menus you can go to every processing algorithm you want to add to your favorites and click on "Add button in toolbar"

After that when you restart QGIS, you will have the selected algorithms right in your toolbars.

Example with "Buffer" and "Centroids":
[image]

As far as I know this is the only thing you can do to facilitate access to processing algorithms to make them "favorites"

Comment: A great possibility I didn't know about! Unfortunately, this doesn't work for all tools. I can't see an additional icon after restarting QGIS for `Geometry by Expression`, even though the tool is checked int `Processing > Menus`. For your examples (Centroid, Buffer) it works. Might it be that if there does not exist an icon it won't be added? Or does it has to do with the `Menu path` that is empty?

Comment: I didn't notice that but you are accurate in that the problem comes from the `Menu path` if you set it correctly it works fine (the same as `Centroids`)

Comment: A problem is that there are identical icons or no icons for some so if you used this you would probably want to add identifying icons to the algorithms you want to use that don't already have one

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the answer by @Louis Cottereau

When you want to add an icon for a tool/algorithm that does not yet have an entry in a menu, you must first include the tool/algorithm to a menu. To do this, use the entry `Menu path` and paste a path - for `Menu Vector > Geometry tools`, use `Vect&or/G&eometry Tools`. Then clik `Add button in toolbar` (see screenshot below, left side).

The icon that will be created is the one you can see next to the tool's entry in the processing toolbox (see on the right of the screenshot below). Many tools/algorithms do not have a proper icon, but just use the default gear-icon. You might change the icon in the middle in the field called `Icon` by adding the path to your custom icon file.

By the way: if you add icons this way, a new toolbar called `Processing Algorithms` is added - you can show/hide it in `Menu View > Toolbars`.

[image]